# MMENU jquery plugin doubles all JS scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

When I'm using mmenu jquery plugin, it doubles all js events and script call, except scripts in head section. What would be the possible solution for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry, but I can't show you full code, it's on working site. Mmenu starts that way in body section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#my-menu").mmenu(); 
      $("#my-menu").find( ".mm-subopen" ).addClass( "mm-fullsubopen" ); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll have this problem with any javascript inside your body tag (I'm having the issue with analytics being fired twice) it's due to the offcanvas plugin moves the whole body into a sub div causing all JS to be processed twice.

Comment: https://github.com/BeSite/jQuery.mmenu/issues/444 try there for some answers

Answer (score 0):

i tried mmenu in my production app and at first it gave me some headaches, but understanding how it works helped me to use it correctly.

1. Wrap your whole layout in a `div` without styles (so the website's style remains the same).
2. Place your menu markup **outside** your layout (inmediately bellow the `body` tag).
3. Add the the plugin at the end of your markup along with the initialization code.
4. **Don't** manipulate the inner content of the menu to do actions. Use it's **API** instead.

After you follow these tips, you should have a structure like this:

```
<html>
  <head> ... </head>
  <body>
    <nav id="mymenu"> ... </nav>
    <div> <!-- whole website in here -->  </div>
    <script src="js/mmenu.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() { 
        var mmenu = $("#mymenu").mmenu(); 
        // do not use code bellow, use the API instead. 
        // $("#my-menu").find( ".mm-subopen" ).addClass( "mm-fullsubopen"       );
        var api = mmenu.API(); // exposes methods to open() and close() the menu 
    });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope these setup works for you. It worked for me perfectly in my Meteor app.